# Перебрать два списка при этом второй сдвинуть на шаг

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброе время суток!
существует два списка (координаты x,y) для отрисовки N объектов в бесконечном цикле. Необходимо при переборе списка, второй одновременно сдвигать на шаг. Задача вроде простая, но ни как не получается корректно выполнить сдвиг на шаг

```
row_x = []
row_y = []
while True:
    for x, in row_x:  
        for i, y in enumerate(row_y):  # Этот цикл точно лишний, но без него не получается
            row_y[i] -= 5
            point = (x, y)
            .....
```

При такой конструкции кол-во объектов удваивается.

Answer (score 2):

Задача не только простая, но и описанная в документации:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for x, y in zip_longest(row_x, row_y[1:]):
    point = (x, y)
```

Если нужна модификация исходного списка (хоть я и не вижу в коде, зачем это может понадобиться):

```
for i, x in enumerate(row_x):
    if i < len(row_y) - 1:
        row_y[i + 1] -= 5
```

**UPD:**

Сдаётся мне, что изначальная формулировка вопроса мало общего имеет с реальной задачей... Вероятно, вам нужно что-то такое

```
for x, y in zip(row_x, row_y):
    point = (x, y - 1)
```

Comment: а что дает второй аргумент в `next()` ?

Comment: @finally гарантию того, что не будет выброшено исключение.

Comment: вместо `None` можно передать все что угодно? например вызов функции, или другой генератор?

Comment: @finally [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

Comment: Я конечно не сильна в Pythin, но мне кажется функция **pairwise(iterable)**: должна принимать два параметра, так передаем два параметра. При такой конфигурации не работает.

Comment: @Botkin вы правы. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Извиняюсь конечно, за бестолковость (что-то у меня именно на этом моменте затык произошел), списки имеют аз ведомо одинаковую длину. Если произвести сдвиг по у то рисуемый объект начнет двигаться вниз. Мне не понятно zip_longset - для списков разной длины, но можно это не учитывать, но я так и не пойму как сдвинуть на определенный шаг y

Comment: @Botkin а как вы представляете сдвиг на списках одной длины? Предположим, у вас есть `[1, 2, 3]` и `[4, 5, 6]`, при сдвиге на шаг вперёд на последней итерации будет выход за пределы второго списка. Что в таком случае должен делать ваш код?

Comment: Я видимо не корректно выражаюсь. Нужно следующее x = [1,2,3] и y = [4,5,6] необходимо из координаты y например вычитать 1 т.е. должен получиться список y = [3,4,5] и тогда объект начнет двигаться вниз

Comment: Угу, никак вас не пойму. Вам надо просто совместно проитерировать списки?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я решила проблему

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Проблема решилась так:                                             for j, y in enumerate(row_y): 
        point = sd.get_point(row_x[j], row_y[j]) 
        row_y[j] -=15

Comment: Понять не могу как правильно отвечать на данном форуме